# Carrierwave MiniMagick Cropping multiple versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

I'm doing some cropping with carrierwave using minimagick. I have 3 sizes, and currently the cropping works fine for the large size, but the smaller sizes seem to ignore the cropped image and resize from the original image.

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::Processing::MiniMagick
  version :thumb, from_version: :medium do
    process resize_to_fill: [100, 100]
  end

  version :medium, from_version: :large do
    process resize_to_fill: [261, 163]
  end

  version :large do
    process :conversion
  end

  # ... some methods
  private

  def conversion
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.format('JPG')
      img.strip
      if model.croppable?
        img.crop("#{model.w}x#{model.h}+#{model.x}+#{model.y}")
      end
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end
end
```

How do I tell the medium to resize_to_fill from the cropped large version, and not the original version?

Comment: What version of carrierwave are you using?  Also, you might want to try reversing the order those versions are listed... (e.g. put large first, then medium, then thumb)

Comment: gem 'carrierwave', '0.9.0'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', '0.6.3', require: 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem 'carrierwave-processing', '~> 0.0.2'

I'll try reversing the order. I didn't think about that one.

Answer (score 1):

As @PinnyM suggested, it was the order in which the versions were specified

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::Processing::MiniMagick

  # Specify this first!
  version :large do
    process :conversion
  end

  version :medium, from_version: :large do
    process resize_to_fill: [261, 163]
  end

  version :thumb, from_version: :medium do
    process resize_to_fill: [100, 100]
  end

  #... everything else
end
```